# Enviar mensajes a numeros no registrados con whatsapp business

Tags: json, facebook, whatsapp

Quiero enviar un mensaje a un numero que no haya registrado desde la pagina de facebook developers con la api de whatsapp business

este es el json que envio a la siguiente direccion:

[https://graph.facebook.com/{{Version}}/{{Phone-Number-ID}}/messages](https://graph.facebook.com/%7B%7BVersion%7D%7D/%7B%7BPhone-Number-ID%7D%7D/messages)

```
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "{{Recipient-Phone-Number}}",
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "name": "hello_world",
        "language": {
            "code": "en_US"
        }
    }
}
```

en mi caso ya he probado el Recipient-Phone-Number con 2 numeros registrados y funciona correctamente, pero quiero que funciones para numeros que no tengo registrados.

me retorna este error en json:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#131030) Recipient phone number not in allowed list",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 131030,
        "error_data": {
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "details": "Recipient phone number not in allowed list: Add recipient phone number to recipient list and try again."
        },
        "error_subcode": 2655007,
        "fbtrace_id": "AWx3kw4qh4leKEYAC0djmra"
    }
}
```

como puedo hacer que funcione?

Comment: La API de WhatsApp Business que estás usando es una prueba, por ende sólo podés mandar mensajes a números previamente registrados. Para usar la versión en producción (y por lo tanto poder mandar mensajes a quién sea) tenés que poder justificar a Meta que tenés un negocio funcional, o al menos eso fue antes cuando traté de usar la API

Comment: Cual {{Phone-Number-ID}} estas usando? el del Test Number? porque si es asi siempre te va a dar ese error.

Answer (score 1):

El problema tiene que ver con el "1" que se agrega para algunas regiones después del código de país.

Un ejemplo para México: el número completo es (+52)5543223352, sin embargo facebook te dice que el número es enviado desde el 5215543223352, pero debes eliminar el 1 en la tercera posición, es decir, el destinatario debe ser 525543223352

Comment: ese no es el problema, quiero enviar mensajes a numeros que no tenga registrados previamente

Comment: Esto solucionó mi problema. Removí el 1 de 52155 y eso fue suficiente.